# How to match backslash at beginning of line in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, delimiter, backslash

After seeing some errors showing up in our apache logs, I've been trying to figure out 'why'. The errors related to a preg_match command where I was trying to find strings that started with a backslash character:

```
preg_match('/^\\/',$str)
```

It was reporting "preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"

Out of curiousity I tried double instead of single quotes, and combinations from 1 to 6 backslashes and it always reports the same error. (I ended up switching the test to if(substr($str,0,1) == "\") {} instead for the time being)

Comment: Why not `substr($str, 0, 1) === '\\'` or even `$str[0] === '\\'`?

Comment: @Gumbo: I had to think twice about `===` to realize that it is indeed required to eliminate false positives. Did you do that on purpose or just a good habit? Thanks for the "mental correction"! :-)

Comment: @Gumbo: ...aaand it turns out it's not required after all. WTF php, I thought `'0' == '\\'` is `true` because the first is numeric. I need to stop using that language. ;-)

Comment: @Jon Just a habit. If I expect the result being the same data type as the value I’m comparing it to, I’ll use `===`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Good habit. I don't do that enough.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `\\` inside a string literal is translated to a single `\` by PHP.

Therefore your regular expression is `/^\/`, where `\` makes the trailing slash be translated literally as a slash and not as the ending delimiter. That leaves the regex without an ending delimiter, so PCRE complains.

The result you would want to have is `/^\\/`, and to put that inside a string literal you need to double the backslashes, so:

```
preg_match('/^\\\\/',$str)
```

That said, `if($str[0] === '\\')` is much easier to read and faster to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Because `\\` will be escaped as a single `\` you'll need to do:

```
preg_match('/^\\\\/',$str)
```

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out - thanks. Not sure what I did the first time I tried that but I got the same error regardless. Got it to work when rebuilding my test-code from scratch.

Comment: Nice, then select this option as the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

OK, weird, I just ran my tests again from scratch and got it working this time with 4 backslashes as I would have expected. My initial thought was the single quotes was still using the first \ to qualify the second. So I tried four but must have screwed something else up in the syntax.

```
if(preg_match('/^\\\\/', $str)) {}
```

The above works.

Answer (score -2):

I think this might have to do with `'` (single quote)

Try changing them to double quotes `"`. Two `\` should be enough.